# Text widget not displaying in ListTile flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to display a profile image in left section, name and company in middle section (one below other) and reviews and ratings in right section inside a ListTile. I was able to display an image, reviews and ratings correctly, but text is not being displayed. I want to achieve this:

[image]

The white space between image and ratings is where I want to show the text (name and company, one below other). Not sure what am I missing here.

Code snippet below:

```
return new ListTile(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          leading: _getProfilePic(pro),
      //    title: new Text('${pro.fullname}'),
        title: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text('${pro.fullname}')
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
    subtitle: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
      ),
            new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text('${pro.company}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
    ),
      trailing: new Column(children: <Widget>[
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            new StarRating(starCount: 5, rating: pro.rating, color: Colors.amber),
          ],
        ),
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text('${pro.reviewCount} reviews'),
          ],
        )
      ],) ,
```

---

[image]

---

It seems to me a custom method that return `ListView`, as below:

Widget buildProList(List pros, BuildContext context) {
    List proTiles = new List();

```
pros.forEach((pro) {
  proTiles.add(proTile(pro, context));
});

return new ListView(
  children: proTiles
);
```

}

And this is it's implementation:

ListTile proTile(Pro pro, BuildContext context) {
  return new ListTile {

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the source code of `ListTile` to check how it is building the tree. 
If you read the documentation from `ListTile` widgets you'll find something like this:

```
  /// The primary content of the list tile.
    ///
    /// Typically a [Text] widget.
    final Widget title;

    /// Additional content displayed below the title.
    ///
    /// Typically a [Text] widget.
    final Widget subtitle;

    /// A widget to display after the title.
    ///
    /// Typically an [Icon] widget.
    final Widget trailing;
```

So you have to take in consideration the widgets that you are passing.

Your layout looks to complex, this is an example of how you can build your widget in a very simple way:

```
    new ListTile(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            leading: _getProfilePic(pro),
            title: new Text('${pro.fullname}'),
            subtitle: Text('${pro.company}',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
            ),
            trailing: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new StarRating(starCount: 5, rating: pro.rating, color: Colors.amber),
                new Text('${pro.reviewCount} reviews'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Another solution without using `ListTile`:

```
  return Row(
        children: <Widget>[
        _getProfilePic(pro),

          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(
                  '${pro.fullname}',
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ), 
                new Text(
                  '${pro.company}',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0), 
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new StarRating(starCount: 5, rating: pro.rating, color: Colors.amber)
              new Text('${pro.reviewCount} reviews'),
            ],
          )
        ],
      );
```

Note: Don't forget to check the parent constraints of your child widget

Comment: Yes, I had earlier tried the above approach to keep it simple, but it displayed `fullname` and `company` vertically and the `rating` overlaps it. I wish I could paste a screenshot of it. @diegoveloper

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: Added screenshot in my original question @diegoveloper.

Comment: what is the parent  widget of your ListTile ?

Comment: It seems to be a dynamic `ListView`.. this is what I see in the code.

Comment: I added another option that you can use

Comment: I added the custom method and it's implementation in my original question. Since it's returning a `ListTile`, not sure if it will allow to return anyother widget than `ListTile` @diegoveloper.

Comment: just change this : ListTile proTile(Pro pro, BuildContext context)  to this:  Widget proTile(Pro pro, BuildContext context)  and it should work

Comment: Getting `type 'Row' is not a subtype of type 'ListTile` exception @diegoveloper

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181864/discussion-between-diegoveloper-and-dk15).